# How to remove a class when scroll function is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a header that is sticky when scrolling upwards and not showing when scrolling downwards using javascript, to do that I added a class `.header-up` and gave `transform: translateY(-100%);` through CSS. It's working perfectly fine, BUT when I open the full-page menu in header and trying to close [*no issues when header at the top, but we can see the problem after scrolling a bit from top*] it the class 'header-up' is still there. So the header going upwards behind the viewport area. I tried to remove the `.header-up` class using this code `s.removeClass("header-up")` to make the header stick at the same place. Here goes the **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akhilpaul/zogp9ue6/60/)**

here is the javascript I used for scroll and toggle the full page menu.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var scroll_pos = 0;
        var scroll_time;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      clearTimeout(scroll_time);
      var current_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (current_scroll >= $("#header").outerHeight()) {
        if (current_scroll <= scroll_pos) {
          $("#header").removeClass("header-up");
        } else {
          $("#header").addClass("header-up");
        }
      }

      scroll_time = setTimeout(function() {
        scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
      }, 100);
    });
});



    $("#navbar-toggle").on("click", function(t) {
      var e = $(this).data("scroll-y"),
        i = $(window).scrollTop(),
        n = $("#navbar-toggle"),
        o = $("#overlay-nav"),
        s = $("#header"),
        r = $("body");
      o.hasClass("toggle")
        ? (r.css("top", "0px").removeClass("noscroll"),
          window.scrollTo(0, e),
          o.removeClass("toggle"),
          n.removeClass("open"),
          s.removeClass("overlay-nav-toggled"),
          s.removeClass("pos-fixed"),
          s.removeClass("header-up"),
          setTimeout(function() {
            s.removeClass("suppress-scroll");
          }, 700))
        : ($(this).data("scroll-y", i),
          o.addClass("toggle"),
          n.addClass("open"),
          s.addClass("overlay-nav-toggled suppress-scroll"),
          r.css("top", -i + "px").addClass("noscroll"));
    });
```

Comment: Hello, please include your code in the question.

Comment: @AnisR. just updated the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update this

```
if (current_scroll <= scroll_pos) {
```

with the following

```
if (current_scroll <= scroll_pos || $('#header').hasClass('suppress-scroll')) {
```

Comment: this is exactly I'm looking for Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but is this what you're looking for?

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var headerElement = $('header');

$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       // scroll down
     headerElement.addClass('header-hidden');
   } else {
      // scroll up
     headerElement.removeClass('header-hidden');
   }
   
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  position: relative;
}

header {
  background: white;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  transition: 500ms margin-top ease;
}
header.header-hidden {
  margin-top: -100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <p>header</p>
</header>

<p>accusantium, omnis aut quod, optio eius qui voluptates quae? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint natus rerum cum harum possimus, repellendus alias! Necessitatibus doloremque magnam ex sunt accusantium, omnis aut quod, optio eius qui voluptates quae?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint natus rerum cum harum possimus, repellendus alias! Necessitatibus doloremque magnam ex sunt accusantium, omnis aut quod, optio eius qui voluptates quae? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint natus rerum cum harum possimus, repellendus alias! Necessitatibus doloremque magnam ex sunt accusantium, omnis aut quod, optio eius qui voluptates quae? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint natus rerum cum harum possimus, repellendus alias! Necessitatibus doloremque magnam ex sunt accusantium, omnis aut quod, optio eius qui voluptates quae? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint natus rerum cum harum possimus, repellendus alias! Necessitatibus doloremque magnam ex sunt accusantium, omnis aut quod, optio eius qui voluptates quae? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint natus rerum cum harum possimus, repellendus alias! Necessitatibus doloremque magnam ex sunt accusantium, omnis aut quod, optio eius qui voluptates quae?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint natus rerum cum harum possimus, repellendus alias! Necessitatibus doloremque magnam ex sunt accusantium, omnis aut quod, optio eius qui voluptates quae?</p>
```

**Edit**
Based on the feedback of the owner of this question:
The reason that the header is gone when you click on the button is because your #overlay-nav has **position: fixed** combined with a **top: 0**
the header is still there, but your menu elements are on top off it.

either change `z-index` values or change the `top: 0` values
the code underneath will fix your issue, **but** don't forget to check responsive because you're setting a static value right now

```
#overlay-nav {
   top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I'm trying to achieve when closing the full page menu, I need to stick the header. Now header is disappearing when clicking the close button in full page menu. Please see jsFiddle.